# Problem creating a table with interface not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a [] phases, where I would need to load into a table, for the user to change some data and send to the bank, and also show in a list.

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="budget1">

  <ng-container formArrayName="phases">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let phase of phases.controls; index as i">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                      <td>
                          <h3 formControlName="name" mat-subheader>
                              {{ i + 1 }}. {{ phase.value.name }}
                          </h3>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateStart" formControlName="dateStart">
                          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                          <mat-datepicker #dateStart disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateEnd" formControlName="dateEnd">
                          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateEnd"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                          <mat-datepicker #dateEnd disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                      </td>
                  </ng-container>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>

  </ng-container>

</form>
```

this.budget.phases, comes injected from another form, and is an interface

```
 @Input() budget;
 budget1 = new FormGroup({
    phases: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(''),
        dateStart: new FormControl(''),
        dateEnd: new FormControl(''),
      })
    ])
  });
  
  phases = this.budget.get('phases') as FormArray;
```

But it always returns some kind of error, what would be the best way to make it work ? So far all I've tested haven't worked.

```
phases = this.budget.get('phases') as FormArray;
```

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

In this line returns this error

Comment: Show us the error that you get.

Comment: I edited, with the errors

Comment: Can you provide us the controller to understand how you are binding budget? Otherwise you could just do "phases = budget1.get('phases') as FormArray" as you have it initialized in the same context